# How to wrap DbSet.Include in my own generic interface / class

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, word-wrap

I'm having some problems to solve an issue in my generic implementation.

First of all, what I'm trying to accomplish

I'm trying to implement my own repository (and later my UoW), for this I've:

[This classes, see the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zYAK.jpg)

So, what's the problem?

in my IRepository I've this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    List<T> GetAll();
    /* some other methods*/

    //Here is my problem
    DbQuery<T> Include<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> path);
}
```

and in my class I have this:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly MyDBContext context = null;

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    #region Constructors
       public Repository()
       {
           context = new MyDBContext();
           DbSet = context.Set<T>();
       }

       public Repository(MyDBContext context)
       {
           this.context = context;
       }
    #endregion

    public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.ToList();
    }

    /* more code for the rest of methods*/

    //And here is my problem
    DbQuery<T> Include<T, U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> path) where U : class
    {
        return (DbSet<T>)DbSet.Include(path);
    }
}
```

So, I've tryed to define this method in different ways in the interface but the one I'm using seems to be -at least- the one that defines correctly the method. But in the implementation I'm having an error:

**"The best overload coincidence has some invalid arguments"**

I've tryed removing the T, U in the method definition

```
DbQuery<T> Include(Expression<Func<T, U>> path)
```

but then I can't specify the U and I've the error:

**"Can't find the type or namespace for U, are you missing a directive?"**

If I do this:

```
DbQuery<T> Include(Expression<Func<T, T>> path)
```

I don't have any error but misses the point to use a lambda with different classes

I also had errors like the T is the same in the internal and external definition

The idea later is this repository should be used to define MyRepository like:

```
public class MyClassRepository : Repository<MyClass>, IMyClassRepository
```

and then would be used in the controller like:

```
MyClassRepository repo = new MyClassRepository();
```

and then:

```
repo.Include(o => o.MyOtherClass);
```

For now I've solved this, defining a different method in the interface

```
IQueryable<T> Include(string path)
```

and implemented as:

```
public IQueryable<T> Include(string path)
{
    return DbSet.Include(path);
}
```

but then in my controller I've to use like this:

```
repo.Include("MyOtherClass");
```

which isn't awful but I lose the lambda capability.

So if anyone spots what I'm missing I'll be very grateful.

Thank you all

Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

Remove the generic T declaration from the Include method, because you've already defined it at the class level.

```
DbQuery<T> Include<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> path);
```

Don't forget to make the method public in the implementation and to remove the `U` constraints, since they don't appear in the interface.

---

As a side note `IDbSet` already is a repository and `DbContext` already is an UoW. `IDbSet` makes you think you are working with an in memory collection of entities and `DbContext` tracks the changes made in its `IDbSets` and gives you a method to commit those changes when you're done.

Comment: Adrian, thank you very much, sometimes you have a big grey elephant in front of you and you can't see it!!

I've already implemented and it's working like a charm.

Comment: Great. You should not create the DbContext in the repo classes, but pass it via the constructor so you can properly implement later the UoW.

Comment: @AdrianIftode what about if I want to implement include as ´´i=> i.NavigationProperty´´, not as strings path ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez, I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: @AdrianIftode  Include could be write as: mycontext.Mytable.Include("nav1,nav2").ToList() or mycontext.MyTable.Include(i=> i.nav1).Include(i=> i.nav2).ToList(), I'm interested on implement second option on my repository.

Comment: That's the proper way.

Comment: @AdrianIftode sorry for my ignorance but do you have a sample implementation for one class with two or more navs? I'm totally lost.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez let the Include method to return the same type as the input. For this question it should return IRepository<T> and not DbQuery.